# Server not found on one specific domain

Tags: web, dns

Is there a way to find the reason if a domain shows "Server not found?"

One of my client owns a domain. Now he says that he can access it easily but on my side it says "Server not found"--on all browsers. I asked one of my friend who lives in another country to check the domain. According to my friend, he is also able to access that domain.

Now, I want to find the reason. Why I am the only person who is seeing "Server not found?"

Please, help!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your local computer's DNS Cache in Windows or in Mac:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/ClearingBrowserCache

and your browser's cache also.

http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache

Best Regards